# Get the number of views for a specific map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google maps JavaScript API. Where can I get the API to get the number of views/SEO of my map? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Google Maps APIs Premium Plan**, you can use **Google Maps Usage Reports tool**.

The Google Maps Usage Reports tool helps you track your application's usage of Google Maps Platform and its consumption of Maps APIs Credits. With the tool, you can view detailed daily and monthly reports on all APIs included with your Google Maps APIs Premium Plan. Report data is available for API requests that include either a client ID or a project ID.

You can read all the info in detail in following link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/usage-reports

Comment: You're welcome. Check this out if this works. https://medium.com/@KeywordsHeaven/how-to-rank-higher-on-google-maps-683fa645c414

Comment: I beleive this information is outdated. Can someone update?